# how to restrict selection style based on selected row count in uitableview multiselct in ios swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, multi-select

In here i'm having problem with `tableview` multiselect,can anyone help me. i want to restrict table view selection with certain count of rows(for ex 5 rows from list).selected rows must be in selection style as .blue,when i try to select 6th row that row selection style should be .none.but i tried it with someway is not working fine.

This is my code

```
tableview.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method,

```
if SelectedArray.count <= 5
{
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Blue
} 
else {
      cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
 }
```

and also defined this above declaration in  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`,`willDisplayCell` and also reload my table when `didselectrow` ,

this also tried with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method,

```
self.tableView(tableView, willDisplayCell: cell, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

But there is no use of that,pls help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try <5 instead of <=5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this one

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

    if let sr = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        if sr.count == limit {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message:
                "You are limited to \(limit) selections", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {action in
            }))
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return nil
        }
    }

    return indexPath
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("selected  \(intervalNames[indexPath.row])")

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if cell.selected {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }
    }

    if let sr = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        print("didDeselectRowAtIndexPath selected rows:\(sr)")
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("deselected  \(intervalNames[indexPath.row])")

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .None
    }

    if let sr = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        print("didDeselectRowAtIndexPath selected rows:\(sr)")
    }
  }

}
```

For more Detail please visit this link https://github.com/genedelisa/LimitTableExample

Comment: Thank You very much